# How can I change the css values of the Messenger plugin?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've just put the javascript code of the Messenger plugin on my business web site (discussion plugin) and I would like to change somes values of the css, like the max-height of the discussion box when someone is contacting us. (picture as example) I've tried to affect the message box height with my css file but it doesn't, because the class tag and element of the plugin that I want to affect are load when the user click on "start the conversation". So I don't really know what to do. I've already think about load a css file when someone click on this start button, but I don't know how to do...

Thank you!

The first one is the default max-height
The second one is the one I want.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if I found your question correctly, you want to change the style of an element when the user click "start the conversation" button. here is the code you can try to your file. suppose the button in this code is your button. I am using jquery in my code.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
    $(".container").css("height", "250px");
})
```

```css
.container {
    height: 450px;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: #7012dd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>chang with click</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   
   <div class="container">
       message...
   </div>
   
   <button>change</button>
    
    <script src="jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="java.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: whats the extra script tags at bottom for?

Comment: one of them is linking to jquery and another is my javascript code that I posted.  I past them from my editor, here stack-overflow itself links them.

Comment: Not sure how to add this properly to my code... But if I understand what you did, when we click on the button, there is a java script that execute an css file with the value that I want? Is it possible to have a Javascript code instead of a jquery? thx:D

Comment: Ok, finaly I think how I could add it to my code, but I would prefer to have the jquery in javascript, if you can do this for me please:D

Comment: I could not understand the comment you put, jquery is a JavaScript library. when you add it to your html file you can use its method. for example  ".css("height", "250px")" is one method of jquery. but if you don't want to use jquery I would post another code that has the same work but not using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code with pure javascript:

```js
let but = document.getElementById("btn1");
let container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")

but.onclick = function() {
    container.item(0).style.height = 250 + "px";
}
```

```css
.container {
    height: 450px;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: #7012dd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>chang with click</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   
   <div class="container">
       message...
   </div>
   
   <!-- add id to button -->
   <button id="btn1">change</button>
    

    <script src="java.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```